# Gitlab CI variables and script section give different results

Tags: gitlab-ci

I've searched a lot of examples but they did not work for me.

I'm trying to run linters for changed files when MR is opened.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
run_linters:
  image: python:3
  variables:
    FILES: git diff --name-only $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME | grep *.py
  before_script:
    - python3 -m pip install black==21.5b1
    - python3 -m pip install flake8==3.9.2
  script:
    - echo $FILES
    - git diff --name-only $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME | grep *.py
    - black --check $FILES
    - flake8 $FILES
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

And I'm getting strange output.

`echo $FILES` says `git diff --name-only main | grep incoming_file.py`

`incoming_file.py` is the only file in that MR. Why is it around `grep`?

And `git diff` at script section says `fatal: ambiguous argument 'main': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

1. Why is filename present around `grep`?
2. Why are same `git diff` commands give different result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is filename present around grep?

In bash when you refer to `*` this will expand and try to match the files/directories present in your current path, in your case since only the `incoming_file.py` is present, so it expands to this.

> Why are same git diff commands give different result?

```
variables:
  FILES: git diff --name-only $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME | grep *.py
```

When you define a variable in `variables section`, Gitlab doesnt execute the command, it simple populates the variable `FILES` with the string `git diff --name-only $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME | grep *.py`

Then in the script section, the runner expands `*.py` to `incoming_file.py` and `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME` to `main`

that's why in `echo` you see `git diff --name-only main | grep incoming_file.py`

Here

```
 - git diff --name-only $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME | grep *.py
```

You actually execute the command and you get the mentioned message

Comment: That's clear. Thanks.